# Why are there open cells in my scraped Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Im am trying to scrape developer jobs from indeed.nl to Excel using Python and bs4. Everything works fine but when I open it in Excel, there are extra lines cells between the jobs 
[image: Excel file]

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.indeed.nl/jobs?q=developer&l='

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each job
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"row"})

filename = "indeedjobs.csv"

f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "Company; Job; City\n"
f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    jobtitle = container.a["title"]
    city_container = container.findAll("span",{"class":"location"})
    City_name = city_container[0].text
    company_container = container.findAll("span",{"class":"company"})
    company_name = company_container[0].text

    print("Company: " + company_name)
    print("Job: " + jobtitle)
    print("City: " + City_name)

    f.write(company_name + ";" + jobtitle + ";" + City_name + "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: for you're writing it as csv

Comment: Are you sure that `company_name` has no leading line break?

Comment: This was it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<span class="company">` element starts with a newline and some spaces. Remove those with [.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

You can also consider the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to write well-formatted CSV files. The module will help you with correct escaping of special characters.

Comment: Yes this was it. Thanks a lot for the quick answer!